# Steps to partition hard disk while installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, windows-8

I'm using windows 8 in my lap and I wanna install ubuntu without deleting my windows. I had three drives in my hard disk out of which I managed to create a new empty drive of 50 GB using windows disk partition to install ubuntu on it. This new drive is formatted in NTFS format and is available to use in windows as other drives.

I floated across the question & answer in which there are two things.

1) [Installing ubuntu on empty hard drive (which I do not need)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352)

2) [Installing ubuntu on windows installed hard disk (which I'm supposed to see)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343370#343370)

In the second case, step 4 is *'freeing some space for ubuntu'*. But I have already alloted a new drive of 50 GB in which I gotta install ubuntu.

But however, I do not see the free space as shown in *[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Vwj.png)*  and I'm forced to free some space.

So should I proceed to free some space as usual or do something else to install on that drive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should proceed to delete your 50GB NTFS formatted drive (from the Ubuntu installation wizard) this will mark it as free space. After that you'll need to create a partition for your Ubuntu installation and a partition for the swap in this free space.

Note: Ubuntu cannot be installed on NTFS, you can use ext4 instead.